# Some apps redrawn on file explorer resize - Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, windows-explorer, gpu

When I resize File Explorer some applications are redrawn causing them to flicker. (I say redrawn because what happens looks exactly like when the controls on a WinForms app are redrawn from top to bottom and it takes a couple 100 milliseconds). I checked with a friend and this does not happen to him. The affected apps include:

- Task Manager
- Microsoft Autoruns
- Several of NirSoft's tools
- Device manager
- ClickMonitorDDC
- (CLion and PyCharm also flicker but aren't redrawn in the same way)

Resizing any of the above applications does not have any affect on File Explorer or any of the other applications. Chrome, Spotify, Discord, VLC, iTunes, OneNote, VS 2017, Arduino IDE, and Steam are unaffected. When I resize File Explorer as fast as possible my dGPU spikes to 10%, my iGPU spikes to 30%, and 1-3 threads of my CPU spike to 100%.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? Thanks.

---

## My system:

Dell G3 3579 (i5-8300H / GTX 1050 4GB / plenty of RAM and SSD available)

## I have tried:

- Restarting display drivers.
- Closing all my AHK scripts.
- Closing ClickMonitorDDC.
- Disabling and enabling "Hardware-accelerated GPU scheduling" in settings.
- Disabling and enabling "Launch folder windows in a separate process" under Folder Options.
- Unplugging my external monitor.
- Checking for Windows updates.
- Restarting my computer.
- Updating Nvidia drivers to latest version (466.11).
- Disabling Nvidia drivers from Device Manager.
- Changing the display driver to "Microsoft Basic Display Adapter" in Device Manager.
- Changing the display driver to "Intel(R) UHD Graphics 630" (v 27.20.100.8935 and .9168) in Device Manager.
- Totally uninstalling Clover (never update past version 3.0, it's adware).
- Closing most background apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try using only one GPU with one display at a time. Does the flickering happen regardless of what GPU you are using? It almost seems like Windows 10 is damaged in some way. Performing a full DISM might help.

You could try setting the display refresh rate to 60 Hz:
Go to `Display settings` in Window 10's Settings app, go down to `Advanced display setting`s, then `Display adaptor properties for Display 1`. And then go to the `Monitor` tab and select 60 Hz as the refresh rate.
That might stop the flickering.

Comment: I've tried a whole whack load of things including playing with which GPU is used and the refresh rate of the monitor. At this point I just have a new laptop. Thanks.